# How to increase the number of MAC addresses supported on 3750X?

Tags: cisco

I am seeing the MAC address table is getting full  and there are no more MAC address spaces to give.

Device Model:WS-C3750X-48P
IOS: c3750e-ipbasek9-mz.150-2.SE4.bin 
Total Mac Address Space Available: 0

Is there a way to increase the number of MAC addresses supported on this device?

Comment: Google and/or Cisco can dig up commands to check the amount of RAM (eg show version, show processes memory). If you are having an issue and need help solving it, we need more info. How many MAC addresses are in the table? I think a 3750 supports 6000 addresses. Is it normal to have that many MAC addresses on that switch / network segment? Or are you testing something?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

MAC addresses aren't stored in RAM, but in TCAM. You can adjust the Resource Allocation of your TCAM by using a different SDM profile. The default is 6K unicast MAC addresses. The only profile that offers more space for is the VLAN profile, [which offers 12K address, but reduces the number of routes you can use to 0](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12-2_53_se/configuration/guide/3750xscg/swsdm.html#wp1104164).

Having 6K MAC addresses is indicative of a different problem though. When you see that many MAC addresses on a switch, you might be looking at Layer 2 segments that are too large. When you have too many hosts in the same Layer two segment, you have a lot of overhead of all those chatty hosts. Also, if anything bad happens on the network, and there is no segmentation, everything will be affected.
Also, seeing so many MAC addresses on the 3750X probably means that your network is very oversubscribed, making the 3750X a huge bottleneck.

So, the better question to ask yourself first is: Why are there so many unicast MAC addresses on this switch, and how can this be reduced?

Comment: Segmentation won't help as the switch must know the MAC of every device passing traffic through it. 100 VLANs is 100 segments, but they can all pass through every switch. (but yes, I question his network, too.)

Comment: If you segment the VLANs further downstream, you might be able to reduce the numbers by having a few transit VLANs. It might even be as simple as some of the segments not even needing to traverse this switch at all. But it is a good point that simple segmentation is the solution to the problem. I will edit this.